# How would you prove that the sequence $T_n=\left\lfloor \dfrac{T_{n-1}}{3} \right\rfloor + p$ converges after a finite number of iterations?

Tags: analytic-number-theory, ceiling-and-floor-functions

This problem was posed to me as a dare. I have proven it myself, but I'm curious about what other people come up with, and if someone has a more concise proof than mine. My solution is at the end.

**The problem:**

Choose some positive **odd** integer $p$, and some integer $r$ such that $0 ≤ r ≤ 3p-1$. Consider the sequence $(T_n)$ defined recursively by

$$
T_0 = r \\[2ex]
T_n = \left\lfloor \dfrac{T_{n-1}}{3} \right\rfloor + p
$$

Prove the following:

1. Choose any fixed $p$. Then for all $r$, this sequence always converges to the same value $M$ after a *finite* number of iterations (although the number of iterations required to converge may be different for different values of $r$).
2. Find the convergence value, $M$, in terms of $p$, i.e. $M = M(p)$.

**BONUS POINTS:** Find the maximum number of iterations, in terms of $p$, required for the sequence to converge to $M$, no matter what $r$ is.

$$\\$$

---

*[Stop reading here if you want to attempt it without seeing my solution.]*
$$\\$$

**Proof:**

I will prove that this sequence always converges to $\dfrac{3p-1}{2}$ in a finite number of iterations.

I first prove the case where $p=1$:

Since $0 ≤ r ≤ 3p-1$, we have $0 ≤ r ≤ 2$. Then

$$
T_0 = r \\[2ex]
T_1 = \left\lfloor \dfrac{T_0}{3} \right\rfloor + 1 = \left\lfloor \dfrac{r}{3} \right\rfloor + 1 = 1 \\[3ex]
T_2 = \left\lfloor \dfrac{T_1}{3} \right\rfloor + 1 = \left\lfloor \dfrac{1}{3} \right\rfloor + 1 = 1 \\
$$

and so on. The sequence doesn't change after reaching $1$, and notice that $\frac{3p-1}{2} = \frac{3(1)-1}{2} = 1$, so the sequence indeed converges to $\frac{3p-1}{2}$ in a finite number of iterations.

**For the rest of the proof, $p ≥ 3$.**

I first propose the following explicit formulae for $T_n$ when $r=0$ and when $r=3p-1$:

$$
T_n^{(0)} \stackrel{?}{=} \frac{3p-1}{2} - \left\lfloor \frac{p-2}{2(3^{n-1})} + \frac{1}{2} \right\rfloor, \quad r=0 \\[5ex]
T_n^{(3p-1)} \stackrel{?}{=} \frac{3p-1}{2} + \left\lfloor \frac{p-2}{2(3^{n-1})} + \frac{1}{2} \right\rfloor, \quad r=3p-1
$$
(I arrived at these formulae empirically, and I will prove them here.)

Notice the new notation I've introduced: $T_n^{(X)}$ means $r=X$ for this sequence. I will now prove these formulae by induction, starting with the first formula where $r=0$:

**Claim:** $\quad \forall \ n≥1, \ \ T_n^{(0)} = \frac{3p-1}{2} - \left\lfloor \frac{p-2}{2(3^{n-1})} + \frac{1}{2} \right\rfloor$

1. *Base case:* $n=1$

By definition,

$$
T_1^{(0)} = \left\lfloor \dfrac{T_0^{(0)}}{3} \right\rfloor + p = \left\lfloor \dfrac{0}{3} \right\rfloor + p = p.
$$

And evaluating my proposed explicit formula gives us:

$$
\frac{3p-1}{2} - \left\lfloor \frac{p-2}{2(3^{1-1})} + \frac{1}{2} \right\rfloor = \frac{3p-1}{2} - \left\lfloor \frac{p-1}{2} \right\rfloor = \frac{2p}{2} = p
$$

because $\frac{p-1}{2}$ is an integer since $p$ is odd. Thus the claim is true for $n=1$.

2. *Inductive hypothesis:* Assume the claim to be true for some $n=k≥1$.

$$
T_k^{(0)} = \frac{3p-1}{2} - \left\lfloor \frac{p-2}{2(3^{k-1})} + \frac{1}{2} \right\rfloor
$$

3. *Inductive step:* Prove the claim for $n=k+1$.

$$
\begin{align}
T_{k+1}^{(0)} &= \left\lfloor \frac{T_{k}^{(0)}}{3} \right\rfloor + p \\[2ex]
&= \left\lfloor \frac{\frac{3p-1}{2} - \left\lfloor \frac{p-2}{2(3^{k-1})} + \frac{1}{2} \right\rfloor}{3} \right\rfloor + p \quad \text{by the inductive hypothesis} \\[2ex]
\end{align}
$$

For convenience, let's set $x = \frac{p-2}{2(3^{k-1})} + \frac{1}{2}$ and continue:

\begin{align}
&= \left\lfloor \frac{\frac{3p-1}{2} - \lfloor x \rfloor}{3} \right\rfloor + p \\[2ex]
&= \left\lfloor \frac{\frac{9p-1}{2} - \lfloor x \rfloor}{3} \right\rfloor \\[2ex]
&= \left\lceil \frac{\frac{9p-1}{2} - \lfloor x \rfloor -3 +1}{3} \right\rceil \quad \text{by } \left\lfloor \frac{n}{m} \right\rfloor = \left\lceil \frac{n-m+1}{m} \right\rceil \\[2ex]
&= \left\lceil \frac{\frac{9p-1}{2} - \lfloor x \rfloor -2}{3} \right\rceil \\[2ex]
&= - \left\lfloor \frac{\frac{-9p+1}{2} + \lfloor x \rfloor +2}{3} \right\rfloor \quad \text{by } \lceil -y \rceil = -\lfloor y \rfloor, \ \ y \in \mathbb{R} \\[2ex]
&= - \left\lfloor \frac{\left\lfloor \frac{-9p+1}{2} + x +2 \right\rfloor}{3} \right\rfloor \quad \text{since $\frac{-9p+1}{2}$ is an integer} \\[2ex]
&= - \left\lfloor \frac{\frac{-9p+1}{2} + x +2}{3} \right\rfloor \quad \text{by } \left\lfloor \frac{\lfloor y \rfloor}{n} \right\rfloor = \left\lfloor \frac{y}{n} \right\rfloor \\[2ex]
&= - \left\lfloor \frac{-9p+1}{6} + \frac{x}{3} + \frac{2}{3} \right\rfloor \\[2ex]
&= - \left\lfloor \left( \frac{3p-1}{2} - \frac{3p-1}{2} \right) + \frac{-9p+1}{6} + \frac{x}{3} + \frac{2}{3} \right\rfloor \\[2ex]
&= \frac{3p-1}{2} - \left\lfloor \frac{3p-1}{2} + \frac{-9p+1}{6} + \frac{x}{3} + \frac{2}{3} \right\rfloor \\[2ex]
&= \frac{3p-1}{2} - \left\lfloor \frac{-1}{3} + \frac{x}{3} + \frac{2}{3} \right\rfloor \\[2ex]
&= \frac{3p-1}{2} - \left\lfloor \frac{x}{3} + \frac{1}{3} \right\rfloor \\[2ex]
\end{align}

Substituting back in $x = \frac{p-2}{2(3^{k-1})} + \frac{1}{2}$:

\begin{align}
&= \frac{3p-1}{2} - \left\lfloor \frac{\frac{p-2}{2(3^{k-1})} + \frac{1}{2}}{3} + \frac{1}{3} \right\rfloor \\[2ex]
&= \frac{3p-1}{2} - \left\lfloor \frac{p-2}{2(3^k)} + \frac{1}{6} + \frac{1}{3} \right\rfloor \\[2ex]
&= \frac{3p-1}{2} - \left\lfloor \frac{p-2}{2 \left( 3^{(k+1)-1} \right)} + \frac{1}{2} \right\rfloor \\[2ex]
\end{align}

This final expression is equal to my proposed explicit formula, with $n=k+1$. Thus we have proven by induction that the proposed explicit formula for $T_n^{(0)}$ is correct.

The proof for the proposed explicit formula for $T_n^{(3p-1)}$ is extremely similar to the induction proof above, but simpler. I expect that if the reader can follow the induction proof above, they can trust that the induction proof for $T_n^{(3p-1)}$ would be correct, and thus for convenience I have omitted it here, but know that it's true. Hence we now know two explicit formulae:

$$
T_n^{(0)} = \frac{3p-1}{2} - \left\lfloor \frac{p-2}{2(3^{n-1})} + \frac{1}{2} \right\rfloor \\[5ex]
T_n^{(3p-1)} = \frac{3p-1}{2} + \left\lfloor \frac{p-2}{2(3^{n-1})} + \frac{1}{2} \right\rfloor
$$

We will now prove that both of these formulae converge to $\frac{3p-1}{2}$ in a finite number of iterations. Consider the floor function term in both formulae:

$$
\left\lfloor \frac{p-2}{2(3^{n-1})} + \frac{1}{2} \right\rfloor
$$

One can see that as $n$ grows, eventually the whole expression will evaluate to $0$. This happens when $\frac{p-2}{2(3^{n-1})}$ is less than $\frac{1}{2}$. We can find the point at which this happens:

$$
\frac{p-2}{2(3^{n-1})} < \frac{1}{2} \\[2ex]
p-2 < 3^{n-1} \\[2ex]
\log_3(p-2) < n-1 \\[2ex]
n > 1 + \log_3(p-2) \\[2ex]
$$

Clearly $1 + \log_3(p-2)$ is finite for any fixed $p$, so eventually $n$ will exceed this quantity as we iterate. Thus we have:

$$
\forall \ n > 1 + \log_3(p-2), \\[2ex]
T_n^{(0)} = T_n^{(3p-1)} = \frac{3p-1}{2}
$$

Hence $T_n^{(0)}$ and $T_n^{(3p-1)}$ converge to $\frac{3p-1}{2}$ after a finite number of iterations.

Now we will prove that for all $r$ such that $0 < r < 3p-1$, the sequence $T_n^{(r)}$ is bounded above and below by $T_n^{(3p-1)}$ and $T_n^{(0)}$, respectively. In other words, we want to prove

$$
T_n^{(0)} ≤ T_n^{(r)} ≤ T_n^{(3p-1)}.
$$

We will prove this by induction on $n$.

**Claim:** $\quad \forall \ n≥1, \ \ T_n^{(0)} ≤ T_n^{(r)} ≤ T_n^{(3p-1)} \ \ \text{(for any $0 < r < 3p-1$})$

1. *Base case:* $n=1$

$$
\begin{align}
T_1^{(r)} &= \left\lfloor \frac{T_0^{(r)}}{3} \right\rfloor + p \quad \text{by definition} \\[2ex]
&= \left\lfloor \frac{r}{3} \right\rfloor + p \\[2ex]
&≥ \left\lfloor \frac{0}{3} \right\rfloor + p \quad \text{since $r>0$} \\[2ex]
&= \left\lfloor \frac{T_0^{(0)}}{3} \right\rfloor + p \\[2ex]
&= T_1^{(0)} \\[2ex]
\end{align}
$$

and

$$
\begin{align}
T_1^{(r)} &= \left\lfloor \frac{T_0^{(r)}}{3} \right\rfloor + p \quad \text{by definition} \\[2ex]
&= \left\lfloor \frac{r}{3} \right\rfloor + p \\[2ex]
&≤ \left\lfloor \frac{3p-1}{3} \right\rfloor + p \quad \text{since $r<3p-1$} \\[2ex]
&= \left\lfloor \frac{T_0^{(3p-1)}}{3} \right\rfloor + p \\[2ex]
&= T_1^{(3p-1)} \\[2ex]
\end{align}
$$

thus $T_1^{(0)} ≤ T_1^{(r)} ≤ T_1^{(3p-1)}$.

2. *Inductive hypothesis:* Assume the claim is true for some $n=k≥1$.

$$
T_k^{(0)} ≤ T_k^{(r)} ≤ T_k^{(3p-1)}
$$

3. *Inductive step:* Prove the claim for $n=k+1$.

We have

$$
T_k^{(0)} ≤ T_k^{(r)} ≤ T_k^{(3p-1)} \\[3ex]
\frac{T_k^{(0)}}{3} ≤ \frac{T_k^{(r)}}{3} ≤ \frac{T_k^{(3p-1)}}{3} \\[3ex]
\left\lfloor \frac{T_k^{(0)}}{3} \right\rfloor ≤ \left\lfloor \frac{T_k^{(r)}}{3} \right\rfloor ≤ \left\lfloor \frac{T_k^{(3p-1)}}{3} \right\rfloor \\[3ex]
\left\lfloor \frac{T_k^{(0)}}{3} \right\rfloor + p ≤ \left\lfloor \frac{T_k^{(r)}}{3} \right\rfloor + p ≤ \left\lfloor \frac{T_k^{(3p-1)}}{3} \right\rfloor + p \\[3ex]
T_{k+1}^{(0)} ≤ T_{k+1}^{(r)} ≤ T_{k+1}^{(3p-1)} \\[3ex]
$$

Therefore the claim is true by induction for all $n≥1$.

$$\\$$

Now, for all $n > 1 + \log_3(p-2)$ we have:

$$
T_n^{(0)} ≤ T_n^{(r)} ≤ T_n^{(3p-1)} \\[2ex]
\frac{3p-1}{2} ≤ T_n^{(r)} ≤ \frac{3p-1}{2} \\[2ex]
T_n^{(r)} = \frac{3p-1}{2} \\[2ex]
$$

Hence $T_n^{(r)}$ converges to $\frac{3p-1}{2}$ after a finite number of iterations for all $0 ≤ r ≤ 3p-1$. Moreover, the maximum number of iterations required for convergence is $n = \lfloor \log_3(p-2) \rfloor + 2$. This concludes the proof.

$\blacksquare$

Comment: You may get a better response if you post your solution as an answer, so that people do not suspect you are asking them to do your homework for you

Comment: Re: Henry's comment--- Moreover, giving your solution is necessary if someone wants to see if their solution is "more concise" than yours.

Comment: The reason I didn't post my solution is because I didn't want to influence someone else's approach. I suspect that this problem can be approached in many different ways, and I think my approach was kind of weird, so I'm interested in those other ways that may use better insights. What I don't want is someone looking at my proof and saying "here's how to optimize your solution" but rather, I want to see unique ideas develop organically. However, seeing as my post already has 4 downvotes, I think I'll just post my solution at my earliest convenience. Thanks for the feedback everyone.

Comment: The sequence is either non-increasing, or non-decreasing, based on the initial value $r$, this is easy to prove. Since it is also bounded and integer, it must eventually reach a fixed point $M=\lfloor \frac{M}{3} \rfloor+p$. This last condition can be shown to be equivalent to $2M \leq 3p <2M+3$ and since $3p$ is odd, we must have $3p=2M+1$. I think you should also be able to show that $r \leq 3p-1$ is unnecessary (maybe even oddness of $p$ could be dropped, I am not sure about that).

Comment: Yeah, only effect that $p$ being odd has is that it forces the specific fixed value. Still for even $p$ everything works out the same just with $M=\frac{3}{2}p$ or $M=\frac{3}{2}p-1$.

Comment: To your first comment: Forgive my ignorance, I'm not super experienced in proving things, but what makes you say it's easy to prove that it's either non-increasing or non-decreasing based on $r$? I don't see it - may you prove it? Also, how is the condition $M = \left\lfloor \frac{M}{3} \right\rfloor + p$ equivalent to $2M ≤ 3p < 2M+3$?

Comment: To your second comment: Fun fact, the problem actually models a deterministic card trick, which is why it requires odd $p$, so that it always has the same endpoint; we're actually proving that the card trick always works :) .

Comment: I see that we get $3 \left\lceil \frac{2M}{3} \right\rceil = 3p$ but I don't see by what rules (besides intuition) we convert this to the other expression

Comment: Nevermind, I see it now: start with $\frac{2M}{3} ≤ \left\lceil \frac{2M}{3} \right\rceil < \frac{2M}{3}  + 1$ and the rest is straightforward

Comment: As for non-increasing case, $T_{n+1}\leq T_n$ is equiv to $\lfloor \frac{T_{n}}{3} \rfloor+p\leq T_n$ which is equiv to $p \leq \lceil \frac{2T_n}{3} \rceil$, which is equiv to $\frac{2T_n}{3}>p-1$, which is equiv to $T_n > \frac{3}{2}p-\frac{3}{2}$. However, then $$T_{n+1}=\lfloor \frac{T_{n}}{3} \rfloor+p>\frac{T_n}{3}-1+p>\frac{1}{2}p-\frac{1}{2}-1+p=\frac{3}{2}p-\frac{3}{2},$$ which is precisely the same condition but on $T_{n+1}$. So if $r$ was such that $r>\frac{3}{2}p-\frac{3}{2}$, this inductively shows the sequence is non-increasing. Non-decreasing case is similar.

Comment: But aren't you just assuming it's non-increasing at first? How can you assume that without proving it?

Comment: No, thats induction step, you are assuming $T_{n+1}\leq T_n$ and prove it implies $T_{n+2}\leq T_{n+1}$

Comment: Alright, correct me if I'm wrong, but we're allowed to assume $T_{n+1} ≤ T_n$ because obviously we either have $T_1 ≤ T_0$ or $T_1 ≥ T_0$ (or both)? Is that why we can assume that? Then we just do induction?

Comment: Yes that is a base step in the induction.

Comment: Alright thanks a lot, you've given me enough to write a much more concise proof than the one I posted in the question. I'll post the new proof as an answer and give you credit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This more concise solution was formulated by user [@Sil](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/290240/sil).

**Proof:**

We either have $T_{1} ≥ T_0$ or $T_{1} ≤ T_0$ (or both).

*Case 1:* Assume $T_{1} ≥ T_0$. Then we can make the inductive hypothesis $T_{k+1} ≥ T_k$ for some $n=k≥0$. Then

$$
T_{k+2}  = \left\lfloor \frac{T_{k+1}}{3} \right\rfloor + p ≥ \left\lfloor \frac{T_k}{3} \right\rfloor + p = T_{k+1}
$$

Thus by induction $T_{n+1} ≥ T_n$ so the sequence is non-decreasing.

*Case 2:* Assume $T_{1} ≤ T_0$. We can use the same logic as above to conclude that in this case, the sequence is non-increasing.

Thus the sequence is **monotonic**.

We can also reason that the sequence is bounded. It's obviously always non-negative so it's bounded below by $0$. And notice that $T_0 = r ≤ 3p-1$ so we can make the inductive hypothesis $T_k ≤ 3p-1$ for some $n=k≥0$. Then

$$
T_{k+1} = \left\lfloor \frac{T_k}{3} \right\rfloor + p ≤ \left\lfloor \frac{3p-1}{3} \right\rfloor + p = 2p-1 ≤ 3p-1
$$

Thus by induction $T_n ≤ 3p-1$ so the sequence is bounded above by $3p-1$. Hence the sequence is **bounded**.

> **Side note**: Similarly, it's easy to show $T_n ≤ 3p+r$ if we start with $T_0 = r ≤ 3p+r$ for *any* $r≥0$. However, to be consistent with the premise of the problem, I proved it for only $0≤r≤3p-1$.

Since the sequence is monotonic, bounded, and integer, it must eventually reach a stable value after which *each term equals the next*. We can find this stable value $M$:

$$
\begin{align}
M = \left\lfloor \frac{M}{3} \right\rfloor + p \quad \tag*{since each term equals the next} \\[2ex]
\frac{M}{3} + p - 1 < M ≤ \frac{M}{3} + p \\[2ex]
M + 3p - 3 < 3M ≤ M + 3p \\[2ex]
M-3 < 3M-3p ≤ M \\[2ex]
-2M-3 < -3p ≤ -2M \\[2ex]
2M ≤ 3p < 2M+3 \\[2ex]
\end{align}
$$

And since $3p$ is odd, then it must equal $2M + 1$, hence

$$
2M+1 = 3p \\[2ex]
M = \frac{3p-1}{2} \\[2ex]
$$

Thus we have proven that the sequence converges to $\frac{3p-1}{2}$ after a finite number of iterations. This concludes the proof.

$\blacksquare$

---

**NOTE:** Unlike my original solution posted in the question, this solution doesn't prove that the maximum number of iterations required to converge is $\lfloor \log_3(p-2) \rfloor + 2$. I'm not sure how to succinctly prove this without finding an explicit formula as I did in my original solution. If you figure it out, I'll add it and give you credit.